# How to detect selectbox change in Joomla with jQuery

Tags: jquery, joomla

I need detect change of selectbox (Joomla form field - List) but Joomla classical html select changing to Joomla style and html command is hidden. When i change item in selectbox jQuery not detect this change.

```
    <div class="controls">
        <select aria-required="true" required="required" size="40" class="required chzn-done" name="jform[id_voucher_type]" id="jform_id_voucher_type" style="display: none;">
            <option value="1">Jednorázový</option>
            <option value="2">Opakovatelný</option>
        </select>
        <div class="chzn-container chzn-container-single chzn-container-single-nosearch" style="width: 220px;" title="" id="jform_id_voucher_type_chzn">
            <a tabindex="-1" class="chzn-single"><span>Opakovatelný</span><div><b></b></div></a>
            <div class="chzn-drop"><div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly=""></div>
            <ul class="chzn-results">
                <li data-option-array-index="0" style="" class="active-result">Jednorázový</li>
                <li data-option-array-index="1" style="" class="active-result result-selected">Opakovatelný</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried some ways to set listener but nothing work.

```
    jQuery("#form_id_voucher_type").change(function() {
        alert("yeah");
    })
```

Is there any way to detect if user change selectbox item?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id selector is incorrect, is it `jform_id_voucher_type` or `form_id_voucher_type` without `j`, try this :

```
jQuery(".controls").on("change", "#jform_id_voucher_type", function() {
    alert("yeah");
});
```